# issue with writing ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

Hello guys i have a really little experience working with ansible, but today my boss told me that i should write ansible playbook for checking disk space in the production machines
we have a 15 machines and i want to enter each of them, then execute the 'df -h' command, then send output to the email.
can you give me a template of this playook? like this

```
host <ip address>
command <df -h>
SendToEmail <emails...>
```

thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Have you even tried to write something?

Comment: Do you have to write a playbook, or can you simple use the shell module? i.e. ansible -m shell -a 'df -h' all (add machine ips to /etc/ansible/hosts). Then use the output of that however you like.

Comment: Nope ,but this is very important task

Answer (score 1):

Okay I will try to give you a place to start.

Basically, you need to generate an ssh key on the server where you will be running Ansible from (consider this your Master or Control Server).

Then copy your ssh key to every one of the 15 Servers you wish to execute a command on using Ansible. (ssh-copy-id ). Unless of course you like typing your username and password 15 times every time you run the command below.

Once that task is out of the way: 
1) Edit the Ansible hosts file in /etc/ansible (/etc/ansible/hosts) and add the ip addresses under a block. The file should look like this:

```
[servers]
ip1.xxx.xxx.xxx
ip2.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

2) Run the command

```
ansible -m shell -a 'df -h' all
```

This will get you started, you can then use this output to send an email using some sort of mail client.

Caveat, this is not a playbook. You should read up on how to create a playbook if you would like to do it this way.

Comment: Thank youu for you help!

Answer (score 0):

-Create a ansible hosts file as @Jesse said.

-Example playbook:

```
- name: Test 
  hosts: servers
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
      - name: Test 
        command: df -h
        register: output
      - debug: msg='{{output.stdout_lines}} | Mailx -s "{{ ansible_ssh_host }} Info space" usuario@ejemplo.com'
      - name: Send mail with mailx
        command: '{{output.stdout_lines}} | Mailx -s "{{ ansible_ssh_host }} Info space" usuario@ejemplo.com'
```

-Run with: `ansible-playbook playbook.yml`

-Or run with if ansible host file has other path: `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.yml`